# How to map IDictionary<Enum, bool>?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

How do I map Dictionaries with FluentNHibernate?

```
IDictionary<SomeEnum, bool>
```

and..

```
IDictionary<string, bool>
```

?

like:

```
public class SomeClass
{    
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public IDictionary<SomeEnum, bool> Dictionary2 {get;set;} 
   public IDictionary<string, bool> Dictionary1 {get;set;} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the mapping for Dictionary can be done as follows:

```
// IDictionary<string, bool>
HasMany(x => x.Dictionary1).AsMap<string>("keyColumn").Element("Enabled");

// IDictionary<SomeEnum, bool>  (Enum will be mapped as int)
HasMany(x => x.Dictionary2).AsMap("SomeEnum").Element("Enabled");  

// IDictionary<Entity, string>
HasMany(x => x.Dictionary3).AsEntityMap().Element("valueColumn");
```

Comment: How can I map an `Enum` as `string` in the second case?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't map dictionary to the database. Moreover, there is no equivalent for enum in SQL Server. To implement `IDictionary<string, bool>`, I guess, you need to create separate table, that will contain Id, your String, Boolean values and FK to SomeClass (many-to-one relationship). With enum dictionary is the same case, but the contents of that foreign table depends on your needs.